# jQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression | Symbol [ and ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've read in stackoverflow about this issue. However I'm not being able to solve my problem.

I know the issue is in:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
 };
```

My error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #form-group-object1[13][attribute[0]][is_ok]
```

I know the issue is when I do this:

```
var name = $(this).attr('name')
```

This variable contains the symbols **[** and **]**.

How can still use this symbols, but make it to work?

Comment: The element ID syntax seems to be out of order `[13][attribute[0]][is_ok]`

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little? This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrgfb5xe/2/) replicates your question as I understand it, and seems to function just fine

Comment: Since you are retrieving a string, it can have these symbols. Probably the error happens when you use the variable below.

Comment: Have you tried [escaping it](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)?

Comment: post the html of the actual element you are trying to access and how you build the selector.